# How to make the same Key Action event do different actions for every single use

Tags: java, swing

I've been wanting to make my key event make do different things to a `JLabel` every time I use it, for instance: first time pressing right key changes the image in the label to one thing and the next time pressing the right key changes the image to a different image and so on.
heres my code:

`Movement` class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Movement
{
    public JLabel jt;
        public InputMap ip;
        public ActionMap ap;
        public String comm;
        public KeyStroke key;
        public int movement;

        public Movement(JLabel jt, InputMap ip,ActionMap ap, String comm,KeyStroke key)
        {
            this.jt = jt;
            this.ip = ip;
            this.ap= ap;
            this.comm = comm;
            this.key = key;

        }
        public void newAction()
        {

            this.ip  = this.jt.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            this.ip.put(key, comm);
            this.ap = this.jt.getActionMap();
            this.ap.put(this.comm, new AbstractAction() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                {

                    int x = jt.getX();
                    int y = jt.getY();
                    if(key ==  KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,0))
                    {
                    if(x==jt.getX()){
                    jt.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\leguy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Stuff\\walksp2.png"));
                    jt.setAlignmentX(jt.getAlignmentX()+5);
                    }
                    if(x==jt.getX()+5){
                        jt.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\leguy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Stuff\\walksp3.png"));

                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("hey2");
                    }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

`Walk` class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.peer.FileDialogPeer;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class Walk
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Study");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(null);
    p.setBackground(Color.white);
    f.setSize(3000,1000);
    f.setContentPane(p);
    String path = new String("C:\\Users\\leguy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Stuff\\stillsp.png");
    JLabel testl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\leguy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Stuff\\stillsp.png"));
    testl.setSize(500, 500);
    testl.setLocation(500,500);
   p.add(testl);

   Movement moveRight = new  Movement(testl, new InputMap(), new ActionMap(), "move Right",KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,0));
   moveRight.newAction();
f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

main method ^

Comment: Use a counter to keep track of how many times the key was pressed.

Comment: In fact, I’m guessing your (currently unused) `movement` field was intended to be that counter.